Setting local SSH daemon but not being able to connect
I have access to a data center but without sudo privileges.
1. Description
The datacenter has a login node (to which I log in) and several compute nodes. (The usual I guess). I am particularly interested in working with Node11 and Node12. The nodes share the same file system
2. The original problem
Originally I am trying to run mpirun with two nodes. So for example I tried
[me@login]$mpirun -np 2 ./build/all_reduce_perf -b 8 -e 128M -f 2 -g 1


but since it failed, I simplified what I am trying to do first to
mpirun -np 2 -host localhost,node12 hostname

Now, I have tried this from the login node and after accessing node 11 with
srun -p partitionV100 --nodelist Node11 --gres=gpu:8   --pty -u bash -i

I also tried the above mpirun command. In both cases they failed but differently.
In the node11 it failed because node12 was not in the current allocation and in the login node it failed because it was asking the password without a terminal
3. The current problem
So I learned that it was necessary for the nodes to be able to reach the other passwordless. Since I am a user not a root I set to setup a local SSH daemon and this is the problem of this question
4. What I did

A. Check if port 2222 was available

ss -tuln | grep ':2222'

It was in both the login node and node 11

B. Create a directory for SSHD configuration

mkdir -p ~/ssh-server


C. Generate SSH server keys

ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -f ~/ssh-server/ssh_host_rsa_key -N ''


with that we get the keys (public and private) in the ssh-server folder

D Write a sshd_config file

Created ~/ssh_server/sshd_config with the contents
Port 2222
HostKey ~/ssh-server/ssh_host_rsa_key
PidFile ~/ssh-server/sshd.pid
AuthorizedKeysFile ~/ssh-server/authorized_keys
Subsystem sftp /usr/lib/ssh/sftp-server
# UsePAM no
PasswordAuthentication no
PermitRootLogin no
AllowTcpForwarding yes


E Add the public keys to the authorized_keys file

cat ~/ssh-server/ssh_host_rsa_key.pub >> ~/ssh-server/authorized_keys 


F Change permissions

chmod 600 ~/ssh-server/authorized_keys 


G start the ssh daemon

/usr/sbin/sshd -f ~/ssh-server/sshd_config 


H Check if the server is running

$ss -tuln | grep ':2222'
tcp    LISTEN     0      128       *:2222                  *:*                  
tcp    LISTEN     0      128      :::2222                 :::*   

I have checked with ps aux | grep sshd to see if the ssh daemon is running and it is
I have also used the configuration mode (-T) in /usr/sbin/sshd -f ~/ssh-server/sshd_config -T to check if the configuration is applied
However after all of this the final test
Check connection
[me@login]ssh -v -p 2222 -i ~/ssh-server/ssh_host_rsa_key me@node11
OpenSSH_6.6.1, OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 56: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to compute11 [10.3.25.12] port 2222.
debug1: connect to address 10.3.25.12 port 2222: Connection refused
ssh: connect to host compute11 port 2222: Connection refused

What is it that I am missing? and how can I set the local ssh daemon correctly so that I can access the other node without passwords? (so that I can run mpirun later)

Connection refused can be produced by firewall rules as well. Although there is no way to check without having root privileges, it's likely that there are iptables rules that only allow traffic on specific ports and -j REJECT the rest.
Contact your cluster operator, as it's a bit unusual for a cluster to not have any form of password-less login between nodes. (Alternatively, set up SSH's connection multiplexing to make the existing password-based connections "effectively password-less".)

I have been told that no firewalls are running on the datacenter. I will reflect on the other part of your answer thanks!
